# Dynamically adding div's and setting onclick value in JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm using vanilla JavaScript to create a photo carousel; reading in values from an external JSON file, then looping through the JSON data to dynamically add thumbnails, a title, and an onclick to the carousel div.  All the images and titles work fine, but the onclick passes only the last value used regardless of which thumbnail is clicked.

Here's the JSON file

```
var Scenes = {
    "Title":["St. Mary Magdalene","Black Mountains","Pen Twyn Glas","Carreg Yr Ogof Cave","Beinn Narnain"],
    "Thumbnail":["TNStMary.jpg","TNMountains.jpg","TNPenTwynGlas.jpg","TNCarregYrOgof.jpg","TNBeinnNarnain.jpg"],
    "PanoSet":["001x","145+","183+","400x","500x"]
};
```

Here's the code that is dynamically adding the thumbnails, titles, and onclick.

```js
var Scenes = {
    "Title":["St. Mary Magdalene","Black Mountains","Pen Twyn Glas","Carreg Yr Ogof Cave","Beinn Narnain"],
    "Thumbnail":["TNStMary.jpg","TNMountains.jpg","TNPenTwynGlas.jpg","TNCarregYrOgof.jpg","TNBeinnNarnain.jpg"],
    "PanoSet":["001x","145+","183+","400x","500x"]
};

var Repeat = (Scenes.Title.length);

for (i = 0; i < Repeat; i++) {
  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'Scene' + i;
  document.getElementById('Carousel').appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).className = "Scene";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.top = "5px";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.left = 5 + (170 * i) + "px";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).onclick = function() {
    addScene(Scenes.PanoSet[i]);
  };

  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'SceneThumbnail' + i;
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById("SceneThumbnail" + i).className = "SceneThumbnail";
  document.getElementById("SceneThumbnail" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + Scenes.Thumbnail[i] + ")";

  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'SceneTitle' + i;
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById("SceneTitle" + i).className = "SceneTitle";
  document.getElementById('SceneTitle' + i).innerHTML = Scenes.Title[i];
}
```

```html
<div id='Carousel'><div>
```

This is the line that appears to be the problem (I included all above so as to give context)

```
document.getElementById('Scene'+i).onclick = function() {addScene(Scenes.PanoSet[i]);};
```

Which ever of the newly created divs I click on, the code "500x" is passed to my addScene function.

I'm expecting that I've over looked something simple.  Can someone offer a solution?

Comment: You don't need to call `document.getElementById('Scene'+i)` over and over, you have the element at `NewDiv` just use that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `i` is muted by you loop, so each click has the same reference to `i`. As above, this is a dupe

Comment: Other than fixing the `i` you could also look into event delegation (onclick event listener on the parent element, get what you need from the event target).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic JS gotcha. Do this:

```
document.getElementById('Scene'+i).onclick = ((id) => () =>addScene(Scenes.PanoSet[id]))(i);
```

You need to bind in the *value* of `i`, rather than a reference. The handler code doesn't get evaluated until it gets executed, so the value of `i` at that time will be the value it has when the loop has completed.

Doing it using an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) creates a context with the correct static value of `i` bound into the scope of the handler that it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can find index like below. Inside `onclick` using `this` you will get `clicked` `div`. Then get `id` with `this.getAttribute('id')` and replace `Scene` with `''`.

```
let x = this.getAttribute('id').replace('Scene', '');
```

Try it below.

```js
let Scenes = {
  "Title":["St. Mary Magdalene","Black Mountains","Pen Twyn Glas","Carreg Yr Ogof Cave","Beinn Narnain"],
  "Thumbnail":["TNStMary.jpg","TNMountains.jpg","TNPenTwynGlas.jpg","TNCarregYrOgof.jpg","TNBeinnNarnain.jpg"],
  "PanoSet":["001x","145+","183+","400x","500x"]
};


var Repeat = (Scenes.Title.length);

for (i = 0; i < Repeat; i++) {
  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'Scene' + i;
  document.getElementById('Carousel').appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).className = "Scene";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.top = "5px";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).style.left = 5 + (170 * i) + "px";
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).onclick = function() {
    let x = this.getAttribute('id').replace('Scene', '');
    console.log(x);
    addScene(Scenes.PanoSet[x]);
  };

  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'SceneThumbnail' + i;
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById("SceneThumbnail" + i).className = "SceneThumbnail";
  document.getElementById("SceneThumbnail" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + Scenes.Thumbnail[i] + ")";

  NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  NewDiv.id = 'SceneTitle' + i;
  document.getElementById('Scene' + i).appendChild(NewDiv);
  document.getElementById("SceneTitle" + i).className = "SceneTitle";
  document.getElementById('SceneTitle' + i).innerHTML = Scenes.Title[i];


}
```

```html
<div id='Carousel'></div>
```